# Remove MongoDB from auto starting on login

Tags: macos, node.js, mongodb, osx-lion

I installed MongoDB through home brew on osx lion but for some reason, it keeps starting up automatically when I login.

```
>:mongod
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.270 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=52473 port=27017 dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=Mah-iMac.local
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.270 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.5
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.270 [initandlisten] git version: a2ddc68ba7c9cee17bfe69ed840383ec3506602b
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.270 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-2.10gen.cc 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:32:41 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.271 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.271 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb" }
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.272 [initandlisten] journal dir=/usr/local/var/mongodb/journal
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.272 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.328 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 127.0.0.1:27017
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.328 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.328 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 127.0.0.1:28017
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.328 [initandlisten] now exiting
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.328 dbexit: Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.328 [websvr] ERROR:   addr already in use

Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.328 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.328 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.328 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.328 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.328 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.328 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.335 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.337 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.338 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.338 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.338 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Mon Aug 12 20:35:31.338 dbexit: really exiting now
```

How can I remove this from starting up automatically? I don't really use mongo a lot so its kinda not needed and when I do need to use it, it's kinda annoying to get an error when I try to fire it up :/

Answer (score 4):

It should be either:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.mongodb.mongod.plist
```

or

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
```

Comment: thanks but both of those didn't work :( 'No such file or directory'

Comment: Hmm, can you try running 

`launchctl list | grep -i mongo` and `grep -Rl ">org\.mongodb\.mongod<" /System/Library/LaunchDaemons /Library/LaunchDaemons`