# Mongo not working on Mac after update to Mavericks

Tags: macos, mongodb, homebrew

Hi I installed mongoDB on a Mac that was running on Lion and it was working fine.
Later I upgraded my machine to Mavericks and since then I am getting the same king of error as in this post:

[Remove MongoDB from auto starting on login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195338/remove-mongodb-from-auto-starting-on-login)

However, I haven't installed mongo using brew and trying the commands suggested on the link above did not change a thing.
I would like to know how to manually uninstall mongodb so that I can reinstall it and see if I have the same issue.

Can anyone help??

Comment: Can you provide detail on how you installed MongoDB?

Comment: I follow the manual installation detailed here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/
has I didn't have brew...

Comment: As the manual install is just unpacking a gzipped tar and optionally copying the binary, uninstalling should just be deleting unpacked files and any copied binaries. This said, I would not expect MongoDB to autostart unless you took extra steps to set this up. Also, the error in the linked post is simply that another process is running on the same port as MongoDB. Have you tried running mongod with a different port using the --port argument?

Comment: Ok I was thinking about going that way but wanted to know if there was something else I could do about it. I alreayd try other port and try to obtain better error messages, but db is not starting up for some reasons that I do not know, so I think I will just go down the uninstall route, thank a lot.

Comment: Can you post the command you are using to start along with the arguments?

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you mean can you re-explain that?

Comment: I would like to understand how you are launching the mongod process and with what arguments.

Comment: well at first I used **mongoose** to connect to my DB but I was getting some strange error, so I just tried to type the command **mongod** without any arguments and since then I was getting the error mentioned in my question.
I think something went wrong when I went from Mountain Lion to Mavericks...
Does that answer your question?

Comment: If you are seeing the same error as the linked ticket it is likely that mongod is already running. Can you run "ps -ef | grep mongo" in the terminal and provide the output?

Comment: Here is what I got, you were right there was an instance already running.

Yagyuu:apache2 admin$ ps -ef | grep mongo
  503  1050   288   0  5:22   ttys001    0:00.00 grep mongo

Comment: Is this the complete output? Your comment only shows ps finding the grep command we are running on it.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue starting `mongod`?  If you are still having trouble you should edit your description with the specific startup messages you are seeing. These may be similar (but not identical) to the other StackOverflow post you linked.

Comment: @James: I think my answer of yesterday wasn't posted for some reasons but yeah that was the output, there seems to be no mongo instance running...

Comment: @Stennie: nope could not solve it, I think I am just going to go ahead with a reinstall of mongo... Thanks for your help though :)